# Why do you survive 'by the skin of your teeth'?

Tags: etymology, idioms

If someone does something 'by the skin of their teeth', it means they just barely managed to do it.  What is this idiom supposed to be referring to exactly, and how did it originate?

Comment: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19272/which-saying-is-correct) No skin off my nose/teeth

Comment: @Fumble: isn't that more than simply related?

Comment: @Alenanno: Well no-one's voted to close this one as a dup. Your answer on the other gives the definition OP already knows here, but the focus there is on *No skin off my nose* anyway. I see nothing about how the meaning of *By the skin of your teeth* came about. Which I think is a bit trivial, but there you go.

Comment: Besides this question asks also about the etymology, while the other one not.

Comment: Related: "Finer than frog hair"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because (of course) your teeth don't have skin, the expression

> by the skin of your teeth

suggests 'by the smallest possible margin'.

[This reference](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/83000.html) claims an origin in *The Geneva Bible* 1560.

Answer (score 5):

The origin is a quote from the Bible. Job, a pious man, was tested by the god. He lost family, friends, money and health. At the end, he still kept the faith. He escaped, but remained with nothing. In this sense, he escaped with "the skin of his teeth", since the teeth do not have skin.
(source consulted: [Carnal knowledge, C.Hodgson](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004E3XEJ8) )

Comment: That's not quite the modern meaning, though, is it?  The modern meaning is 'just barely', rather than 'coming through something and having nothing afterwards'.

Comment: you are right Jez

Comment: The verse is Job 19:20.  Some translations have him escaping **with** the skin of his teeth, others **by** the skin of his teeth.