# Where does the phrase "No skin off my teeth/nose" come from?

Tags: etymology, slang, figures-of-speech

The phrase "it's no skin off my nose/teeth" is generally used to mean that something isn't much of a risk/concern. But where does it come from? Specifically with respect to teeth. What is tooth skin?

Comment: Tooth skin! That's gums, right? ;)

Comment: @MarkBeadles I'm not at liberty to lol. This is Stack Exchange: a sense of humor is considered a sin.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19272/which-saying-is-correct

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"No skin off my teeth" is not an expression in the UK. Apparently it does exist [in the US](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/It%27s+no+skin+off+my+teeth) where it means "no skin off my nose".

Saying "X is no skin off my nose" means that X occurring won't affect you in a positive or negative manner, the outcome will be neutral to you. The phrase is explained by [phrase finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/6/messages/1131.html) as being of boxing origin. I assume because boxers' noses are the body part most prone to damage.

As James McLeod points out "skin of my teeth" means *only just* or *barely*. [This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35314/why-do-you-survive-by-the-skin-of-your-teeth) addresses its origin.

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/It's+no+skin+off+my+teeth.  This is a saying, I've heard it used, and it's defined in a great many places on the net.

Comment: @NathanC.Tresch that link takes me to "It's no skin off my nose". I guess it's just Americans who use "It's no skin off my teeth" as I've never heard it.

Comment: That page also discusses teeth. :)

Comment: +1 for mentioning "The skin of your teeth". I think it's good to note that this is where the mixed metaphor probably came from. Interestingly, as an American, I've never heard anybody say "No skin of my teeth". It's usually "back", rather than "teeth".

Comment: Contrary to what is written above, "no skin off my teeth" *is* an expression used in England, or at least certainly in my part of the country (Hampshire). My parents (both from the twenties) certainly used it.

Comment: @user30942 (who appears to have left the building) - I've never heard in the UK _no skin off my teeth_ - London and Sussex area. My parents are from the 1910's.

Answer (score 11):

This [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=no%20skin%20off%20my%20nose,no%20skin%20off%20my%20teeth&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) suggests *no skin off my nose* is more common and originated around 1930, and *no skin off my teeth* around 1940.

[image]

*Modern proverbs and proverbial sayings* from [1989](http://books.google.com/books?id=TuHWAAAAMAAJ&q=%22no%20skin%20off%20my%22&dq=%22no%20skin%20off%20my%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-9ePT-n2J4Xl4QT_k9nMBA&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAQ) gives the following:

> **1929** WFaulkner *Sound* (NY) 307: It was no skin off my back. **1932** MTurnbull *Return* (P) 90: 'Tain't no skin off my nose. **1933** WMarch *Company* K (NY) 141: It's no skin off my back-side. ...
>
> **1952** HWaugh *Last Seen* (NY) 87: It's no skin off my teeth whether she's alive in Michigan City or dead in Boston. **1954** HStone *Man Who* (NY 1957) 15: Fatso was no skin off his nose. ...

[Cambridge Idioms Dictionary, 2nd ed.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/It%27s+no+skin+off+my+teeth) gives geographical usage:

> **It's no skin off my nose.**  (*British, American & Australian informal*) also **It's no skin off my (back) teeth.** (*American informal*)
> something that you say which means you do not care about something because it will not affect you *We can go in his car if he prefers. It's no skin off my nose.*

### No skin off my nose

The earliest "no skin off my nose" I found in Google Books is from a [1910](http://books.google.fi/books?id=cJDNAAAAMAAJ&q=%22no%20skin%20off%20my%20nose%22&dq=%22no%20skin%20off%20my%20nose%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=llSQT4-rNfHa4QSonLjMBA&redir_esc=y) *The Cosmopolitan: Volume 49*:

[image: ... an' I'll shore have it or have war.' "'Which I harbors no notion,' the professor protests, continyooin' to be deprecatory, 'of tryin' to make it otherwise. Your romancin' 'round single that a-way ain't no skin off my nose.]

And a [1910](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22no%20skin%20off%20my%20nose%22&num=20&hl=en&safe=off&sa=X&ei=L9yPT6HMFMjd4QTXnvy9BA&ved=0CBsQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1,cdr:1,cd_min:,cd_max:12/31/1911&tbm=bks) *The Saturday Evening Post: Volume 183, Issue 2*:

> “Of course, Max," Abe added, using his partner's metaphor, “it ain't no skin off my nose, y'understand." “Ain't it?" Max growled as he turned on Abe with a menacing glare. “Well, it's a wonder it ain't, the way you are sticking it into ...

Earlier than this, losing the skin [off your nose](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&hl=en&safe=off&tbs=sbd:1,cdr:1,cd_max:12/31/1911&tbm=bks&q=%22skin%20off%20my%20nose%22&oq=%22skin%20off%20my%20nose%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_nf=1&gs_l=serp.3...54782.54782.0.55094.1.1.0.0.0.0.78.78.1.1.0.ZjiGzzxmw0o) would happen after a long, tough journey in the sun, or from the intense frost of a cold journey.

### No skin off my teeth

Answers to another question here at [EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19272/which-saying-is-correct) suggest the -teeth phrase is a combination of
*by the skin of one's teeth* and *it's no skin off my nose*, as [this](http://theminiaturespage.com/plus/msg.mv?id=142117) and [this](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Where_did_this_saying_originate_it%27s_no_skin_off_my_teeth). The -teeth phrase seems to have originated in the southern US. This is a **mixed metaphor**, and yet another variation of "no skin off my nose/back/backside".

The earliest "no skin off my teeth" I found in Google Books is from a [1938](http://books.google.fi/books?id=F5IRAAAAMAAJ&q=%22no%20skin%20off%20my%20teeth%22&dq=%22no%20skin%20off%20my%20teeth%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DNuPT8vUGKqn4gSPz-CABA&redir_esc=y) *The Atlantic monthly: Volume 162*:

> Cap'm,' he said, looking at the ground, 'I'ma man don't never kick in no other man's stall.' 'Well, maybe you do and maybe you don't. **That ain't no skin off my teeth**, and if you get killed messin' around here that won't be nothin' new. Anyhow, it ain't gonna be to-night. You been givin' me the creeps with them songs you been singin'. Now let's hear somethin' lively.

Comment: But what about its origins in the bible? http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_meaning_of_the_idiom_'by_the_skin_of_his_teeth'&altQ=What_does_it_mean_to_escape_'by_the_skin_of_your_teeth'

Comment: "Escape with/by the skin of my teeth" (from the Bible) is a different expression to "it's no skin off my nose/teeth" from your question but there's some [commentary here](http://bible.cc/job/19-20.htm).

Comment: A very good answer. It might be added that it's usually spoken with the emphasis on *my*, so it sometimes means "Your problem, not mine." It strikes me that there might be some seepage from "Cutting off your nose to spite your face", as well&mdash;not in the meaning so much as in the processes (beyond euphemism) which tied the phrase down to the nose rather than other parts of the body.

Answer (score 1):

I'm from the American South, where "no skin off my teeth" is a common phrase. It may be a mixed metaphor, as others have stated; however, it makes sense in that your teeth have no skin and therefore "losing" this nonexistent skin would have no consequence--as in, you can't lose what you don't have. At least that's how I always reasoned it when I would hear the phrase as a youngster.

Looked at in that way, it actually makes more sense than "no skin off my nose." Many Southern Americans have pure British lineage. Perhaps the modern usage in Britain is the mixed metaphor, and the Southern American usage is the same as it was passed down from Colonial Americans? This is all just conjecture on my part. But think about it. It makes sense.

Comment: Welcome, Lynne, and thanks for getting involved on EL&U. We generally want responses to deal with documented facts, or at least opinions based on experience. Plausibility and "how [you] always reasoned it ... as a youngster" don't really constitute evidence here.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "skin of my teeth" is from the Bible, [Job 19:20](http://biblos.com/job/19-20.htm).

Comment: "Escape with/by the skin of my teeth" (from the Bible) is a different expression to "it's no skin off my nose/teeth" from the question but there's some [commentary here](http://bible.cc/job/19-20.htm).